# Data series animation with subplots using GridSpec vs pos

Tags: python-3.x, animation, matplotlib, subplot

I have a number of data series which I want to save as a video. The different data series should appear one by one, keeping the former series. In the end, all the series is shown in the plot. I want to do this with multiple data series/subplots in a synchronized way. I want the subplots to have different sizes, so - as far as I have understood - I need to do this with GridSpec. However, with GridSpec I am not able to keep the old series while adding new ones (I only get the last data series).

An example of my code is (showing the principle - my actual script is more complex):
Working with index/pos (but only equal size on subplots):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim

figure = plt.figure()

data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
set = np.array([1,2,3,4])

def make_frame(i):
    ax1 = plt.subplot(121)
    x = data
    y = i*x
    ax1.set_ylim(0,25)
    ax1.plot(x,y)

    ax2 = plt.subplot((122), sharey = ax1)
    a = data*2
    b = i/x*3
    ax2.plot(a,b) 

    plt.pause(1)

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(figure, make_frame, frames = set, repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

Not keeping old series (but with ability of adjust number of columns/rows for each plot):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec


figure = plt.figure()

data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
set = np.array([1,2,3,4])

print(data,set)

def make_frame(i):
    gs1 = GridSpec(1,2)

    ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,0])
    x = data
    y = i*x
    ax1.plot(x,y)

    ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,1], sharey = ax1)
    a = data
    b = i/x*3
    ax2.plot(a,b)

    ax1.set_ylim(0,25)

    plt.pause(0.5)

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(figure, make_frame, frames = set, repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

How can I keep the "plotting history" in the GridSpec solution?

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the gridspec and the subplots **outside** of the animating function. Else they are recreated from scratch for each frame.

Also, do not use `plt.pause` in an animation, but instead use the `interval` argument. And don't use the names of python functions (`set`) as variable names.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as anim
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

data = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
seti = np.array([1,2,3,4])


gs1 = GridSpec(1,2)
figure = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs1[0,1], sharey = ax1)
ax1.set_ylim(0,25)

print(data,seti)

def make_frame(i):
    x = data
    y = i*x
    ax1.plot(x,y)

    a = data
    b = 3.*i/x
    ax2.plot(a,b)

ani = anim.FuncAnimation(figure, make_frame, frames = seti, 
                         interval =500, repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I needed!